# Using getX for State Management: Blank Screen appears with GetX Controller on First Screen, Works Fine on Subsequent Pages

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm currently using GetX for state management in my Flutter app. However, I'm facing an issue where if I use the GetX controller and try to access certain variables on the first screen, they appear blank. Surprisingly, on all pages after the first one, the variables work as expected.

Here's an overview of my setup:

I have a GetX controller responsible for handling the state and providing data to the screens.
On the first screen, I'm using this controller to retrieve some data, but the variables show up blank.

On subsequent pages, when I navigate using GetX's routing, the variables work perfectly fine.
Has anyone experienced this issue before or can suggest what might be causing this behavior? I've ensured that my state is being properly updated, and the data seems to be available in the controller. Is there anything specific to consider when using GetX on the first screen that could be causing this discrepancy?

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
main code
void main() {
  runApp( const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerHover: (onPointerMove){
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
      },
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        getPages: AppRoutes.appRoutes(),
        initialBinding: InitialBindings(),
        initialRoute: RoutesName.launchScreen,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

LaunchScreen ui code

```
class LaunchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LaunchScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LaunchScreen> createState() => _LaunchScreenState();
}
class _LaunchScreenState extends State<LaunchScreen> {
  final controller = Get.put(LaunchController());
  final AppThemeState _appTheme = AppThemeState();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 25),
        height: controller.height,
        width: controller.width,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(ImageAssetsPath.launchBackImage),
              fit: BoxFit.fill),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Text("Dhulayi.com".tr,
                style: _appTheme.customTextStyle(
                    fontSize: 35, fontWeightType: _appTheme.boldWeightType)),
            SizedBox(
              height: controller.height * 0.02,
            ),
            Text(
              "lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.LoremIpsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
              style: _appTheme.customTextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12, fontWeightType: _appTheme.regularWeightType),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: controller.height * .05,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                controller.navigateToMain();
              },
              height: 50,
              color: AppColors.redBackGroundColor,
              minWidth: controller.width,
              child: Text("Swipe Here",
                  style: _appTheme.customTextStyle(
                      color: AppColors.buttonTextColor,
                      fontWeightType: _appTheme.boldWeightType,
                      fontSize: 20)),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

/// Launch controller code

```
     class LaunchController extends GetxController{
          double height = Get.height;
          double width = Get.width;
        
          void navigateToMain(){
            Get.offNamed(RoutesName.verifyView);
          }
        }
```

when I tried to use width and height using Media Query without using Getx Controller then it worked fine. however i was still using getx controller to call navigation method

Comment: can you please share the code of LaunchController class? @Pratham

Comment: it's written bellow LaunchScreen ui code        
 /// Launch controller code 
class LaunchController extends GetxController{
  double height = Get.height;
  double width = Get.width;

  void navigateToMain(){
    Get.offNamed(RoutesName.verifyView);
  }
}

Comment: In order to display any variable from the controller, you need to manually use update() function if you use GetBuilder.

Comment: if you need any help, please share the github repo or else connect me through gmeet